# Why can`t I assign the props to a constant and render it

Tags: reactjs, react-component

The parent component `Display` gives the props to the child component called `GoodsPresentation`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import GoodsPresentation from "./goodsPresentation/goodsPresentation";
import ShoppingCart from "./shoppingCart/shoppingCart.component";
import axios from 'axios';

class Display extends React.Component {
  
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      products:null
    }
  }

    componentDidMount() {
      
      axios.get( backend)
            .then( response => {
                  this.setState( {
                      products:response.data
                  });
                });
    }

  render() {
    
    return (
      <div>
        <GoodsPresentation productsArray={this.state.products? this.state.products : undefined} />
        <ShoppingCart/>
      </div>
      );
      
  }
}

export default Display;
```

This is forwardes as props:
[productsArray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExhjD.png)

That works very well.

Then I wanted to map the products Array (the props) and assign it to a constant called Data.  Then I wanted to render the Data within the return method of the  child component. This leads to the following error message:

[image]

I dont understand why it doesnt work. What am I doing wrong?
(The commented out mapping under the Data tag works fine)

This is the `GoodsPresentation` Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Table from 'react-bootstrap/Table';

class GoodsPresentation extends React.Component {
  
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
    }
    
  render() {

   const Data = this.props.productsArray != undefined ? this.props.productsArray.map(
      (item,index)=>{
        return (
        <p>Works</p>
       )           
       }  
)
    :null;

    
    return (

      <Table striped bordered hover>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Username</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <Data/>
        {/* {this.props.productsArray != null ? this.props.productsArray.map(
                 (item,index)=>{
                   return (
                   <p>Works</p>
                  )           
                  }  
          )
               :null} */}
         
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    

   
      );
      
  }
}


export default GoodsPresentation;
```

Comment: Data is a react element but is treated as a component. Change it to {Data} in return or to a function where it is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**
i didnt look at your code good enough i guess. The problem is the `<Data />` component. Change that to `{Data}`

Comment: not actually, if it's empty it will throw an error because `undefined` does not implement map.

Comment: look at your link, it's a method implemented at Array object. if it's an empty array returns nothing, but `undefined` does not implement map. you can not call `map` on `undefined`. create an `undefined` variable and try to call map on it.

Comment: @KeatonBenning: I just tried it. In the parent component I deleted the ternery operator. But im still getting the error in the child compoment.

Comment: when I said `empty` earlier I meant if props is `undefined` not that's an empty array. the issue is `productsArray` may be `undefined`.

Comment: @FabianAndiel please review updated answer

Comment: your welcome. please refer to @bhasuru 's comment for the correct explanation as to why that was broke.